# remounting old swap partition not worked in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount

I tried to mount already available swap partition using this method

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l
/dev/sda7       817111040   821108735     1998848   82  Linux swap / Solaris    
/dev/sda8       821110784   900988927    39939072   83  Linux    
Partition table entries are not in disk order    
~$ sudo swapoff -a    
~$ sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/sda7    
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1998844 KiB    
no label, UUID=88052649-8989-4112-accf-594df53783ce    
~$ sudo swapon -a
```

**after this I got this error**

```
swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/fstab` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *attempting* to use the old configuration of an *encrypted* swap with your *current* setup that is not using encryption.

You can:

1. Use your *unencrypted* swap: Change the line in  `/etc/fstab` starting with */dev/mapper/cryptswap1* into

   ```
   /dev/disk/by-uuid/88052649-8989-4112-accf-594df53783ce none swap defaults 0 2
   ```

   and use `sudo swapon -a`
2. Use an **encrypted swap** instead (the recommended way): In `/etc/crypttab`, change the line starting with *cryptswap1* with this one:

   ```
   cryptswap1 /dev/sda7 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
   ```

   and reboot.